# sed replace forward slash with backslash

Tags: sed, makefile, mingw32

I have to convert filenames having a forward slash to filenames with a back slash in a makefile using mingw32. I used the following sed command to store the result in a variable:

```
ORIGINAL=./a/b/main1.c ./a/b/main2.c ./a/b/main3.c
```

**sed command:**

```
RESULT=$(shell echo $(ORIGINAL) | sed 's/\//\\/g')
```

And the **resulting output** is:

```
.\a\b\main1.c .abmain2.c .abmain3.c
```

It works fine if I run it directly on bash. Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That gives me an error in `bash` ("ORIGINAL: command not found" and "shell: command not found"). But this works: `RESULT=$(echo $ORIGINAL | sed 's/\//\\/g')`

Comment: I believe that windows will accept forward slashes: do you *need* to do this?

Answer (score 9):

I'm trying to duplicate your test in a makefile, but I don't have your environment.
But I would not use '/' as a command separator if I am searching for the same character. Use another character, like ':'

```
sed 's:/:\\:g'
```

Comment: This is such a time saver! I wish I knew about changing delimiters in `sed` ahead.

Answer (score 6):

```
RESULT=$(sed 's/\//\\/g' <<< "$ORIGINAL")


$ ORIGINAL='./a/b/main1.c ./a/b/main2.c ./a/b/main3.c'
$ echo "$ORIGINAL"
./a/b/main1.c ./a/b/main2.c ./a/b/main3.c
$ RESULT=$(sed 's/\//\\/g' <<< "$ORIGINAL")
$ echo $RESULT
.\a\b\main1.c .\a\b\main2.c .\a\b\main3.c
```

Comment: This will not work in a makefile, because it's using `<<<` which is a feature of `bash` and not supported in standard POSIX `sh`, which is what `make` uses.  Anyway, the original example works in the shell, there's no need to resort to `<<<`

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the shell that make is invoking is not bash.  However, I find the behavior you're seeing very strange for any shell (it replaces in the first word but not the rest?!?!)

Have you considered using GNU `make`'s `$(subst ...)` function, instead of the shell?

Comment: Replacing slashes: RESULT :=  $(subst /,\\,$(ORIGINAL))